# Condensing a do-while loop to a #define macro

Tags: c++, c, macros, metaprogramming, c-preprocessor

Consider the following sample code (I actually work with longer binary strings but this is enough to explain the problem):

```
  void enumerateAllSubsets(unsigned char d) {
       unsigned char n = 0;
       do {
           cout<<binaryPrint(n)<<",";
       } while ( n = (n - d) & d );
    }
```

The function (due to Knuth) effectively loops through all subsets of a binary string;

For example :

```
33 = '00100001' in binary and enumerateAllSubsets(33) would produce:

00000000, 00100000, 00000001, 00100001.
```

I need to write a #define which would make

```
   macroEnumerate(n,33)
        cout<<binaryPrint(n)<<",";
```

behave in a way equivalent to enumerateAllSubsets(33). (well, the order might be rearranged)

Basically i need the ability to perform various operations on subsets of a set.

Doing something similar with for-loops is trivial:

```
for(int i=0;i < a.size();i++)
    foo(a[i]);
```

can be replaced with:

```
 #define foreach(index,container) for(int index=0;index < container.size();index++)
    ...
    foreach(i,a)
        foo(a[i]);
```

The problem with enumerateAllSubsets() is that the loop body needs to be executed once unconditionally and as a result the do-while cannot be rewritten as for.

I know that the problem can be solved by STL-style templated function and a lambda passed to it (similar to STL for_each function), but some badass #define macro seems like a cleaner solution.

Comment: I would rarely consider a macro a cleaner solution than a function.

Comment: “I need to write a #define …” – naaah, you really don’t need (or want) that. That’s a horrible idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming C++11, define a range object:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <cstdlib>

template <typename T>
class Subsets {
public:
    Subsets(T d, T n = 0)   : d_(d), n_(n) { }
    Subsets begin() const { return *this; }
    Subsets end() const { return {0, 0}; }

    bool operator!=(Subsets const & i) const { return d_ != i.d_ || n_ != i.n_; }

    Subsets & operator++() {
        if (!(n_ = (n_ - d_) & d_)) d_ = 0;
        return *this;
    }

    T operator*() const { return n_; }

private:
    T d_, n_;
};

template <typename T>
inline Subsets<T> make_subsets(T t) { return Subsets<T>(t); }

int main(int /*argc*/, char * argv[]) {
    int d = atoi(argv[1]);
    for (auto i : make_subsets(d))
        std::cout << i << "\n";
}
```

I've made it quite general in case you want to work with, e.g., `uint64_t`.

Comment: I changed the code to eliminate the use of -1 as a termination condition.

Answer (score 2):

One option would be to use a for loop that always runs at least once, such as this:

```
for (bool once = true; once? (once = false, true) : (n = (n - d) & d); )
    // loop body
```

On the first iteration, the once variable gets cleared and the expression evaluates to true, so the loop executes. From that point forward, the actual test-and-step logic controls the loop.

From here, rewriting this to a macro should be a lot easier.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is neat, the only problem is that 'n' needs to be declared outside the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a multiline macro that uses an expression, like this:

```
#define macroenum(n, d, expr ) \
    n = 0;                     \
    do {                       \
        (expr);                \
    } while (n = (n -d) & d)   \
        ;                      \

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{

    enumerateAllSubsets(33);

    int n;
    macroenum(n, 33, cout << n << ",");
}
```

As others have mentioned this will not be considered very clean by many - amongst other things, it relies on the variable 'n' existing in scope.  You may need to wrap expr in another set of parens, but I tested it with g++ and got the same output as enumerateAllSubsets.

Comment: You could actually declare n inside the #define instead of doing it in the caller's scope. Similar to index in foreach(index,container).

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your goal is to be able to do something like `enumerateAllSubsets` but change the action performed for each iteration.

In C++ you can do this with a function in the header file:

```
template<typename Func>
inline void enumerateAllSubsets(unsigned char d, Func f)
{
   unsigned char n = 0;
   do { f(n); } while ( n = (n - d) & d );
}
```

Sample usage:

```
enumerateAllSubsets(33, [](auto n) { cout << binaryPrint(n) << ','; } );
```